# How use Django's ORM for read and write operations from the secondary DB who's models are not present in the project?

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-orm

Here is the current scenario, I have 2 databases in the project

```
DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.postgresql',
        'NAME': 'DB1',
        'USER': 'DB1_ADMIN',
        'PASSWORD': '1234',
        'HOST': 'localhost',
        'PORT': 5432,
        'ATOMIC_REQUESTS': True,
    },
    'crm': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.postgresql',
        'NAME': 'DB2',
        'USER': 'DB2_ADMIN',
        'PASSWORD': '1234',
        'HOST': 'localhost',
        'PORT': 5432,
        'ATOMIC_REQUESTS': True,
    },

}
```

I can use the django's ORM for the **DB1** because it the primary DB of this project, but the **DB2** is the database of another project hence the tables that are in the DB2 are not reflected by models in current project.

I'm able to read and write data from the **DB2** using the raw queries just like below

```
rfp_query = f"""SELECT id, currency, estimated_budget, reconciled_budget, savings, total_items
                                FROM accounting_rfpbudget WHERE rfp_id = {rfp_id}  """
                cursor = connections['crm'].cursor()
                cursor.execute(rfp_query)
```

but I want to use the django's ORM as it takes a lot of effort and time to manage all the stuff on my own, please let me know is there any way to use django's ORM for **DB2** remember there are no models in project that are associated with the database tables.

Comment: please leave a comment if the scenario is not clear, or you want more details, Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Answering my own question, as I just got the solution and it could be helpful for the others, the manage.py offers a very useful command called the inspectdb which will create the all the models for you.
consider the following steps.

1. run command
    `python manage.py inspectdb --database name-of-db  > secondary_db_models.py`
   this will create a file called secondary_db_models.py which will have all the models that were in the db.
   Following is the example of the one model

```
class TicketingServicerequest(models.Model):
    service_request_num = models.IntegerField()
    account_id = models.IntegerField()
    service_request_formatted_num = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    account_name = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    title = models.CharField(max_length=500)
    description = models.TextField()
    status = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    created_at = models.DateTimeField()
    updated_at = models.DateTimeField()
    rfp = models.ForeignKey(EmpeventsRfp, models.DO_NOTHING, blank=True, null=True)

    class Meta:
        managed = False
        db_table = 'ticketing_servicerequest'
```

not you can see the **managed = False** in the class meta which means that this app/project will not maintain the migrations for this model.

2. you have to keep the file above having the models in an app.
3. import models from that file anywhere in the project now and you will be able to use those models.

**an important point to note here is that if the schema of the secondary database changes, then you have to run that command again else the new tables or the models will not show up.**